# R WriteXLS doesn't work on newer R version

Tags: r, excel

I use Rstudio on Windows to develop a shiny app. So far I used R4.0.2 and everything worked fine.
I decided to upgrade R to v4.2.2. My app still works except that writing excel files now fails.

To narrow down the problem I did two fresh installations of R4.0.2 and R4.2.2 with the R binaries on Windows.
Then, on each I did:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("WriteXLS")

WriteXLS::WriteXLS(iris, "test.xlsx", verbose=T)
```

It works fine on R4.0.2 but on R4.2.2 I get:

```
> WriteXLS::WriteXLS(iris, "test.xlsx", verbose=T)
Creating Temporary Directory for CSV Files:  
C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqKhsNt/WriteXLS

Creating CSV File: 1.csv
Creating SheetNames.txt

Creating Excel File: C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\R-4.2.2\bin\test.xlsx

Reading: C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqKhsNt/WriteXLS/1.csv
. No such file or directory\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqKhsNt/WriteXLS/1.csv
The Perl script 'WriteXLSX.pl' failed to run successfully.
Cleaning Up Temporary Files and Directory`
```

I tested also after changing the tempdir but with no success, so it is not a problem of writing rights.

I also tested on another Windows laptop and it works fine. So I don't doubt that WriteXLS is compatible with R4.2.2, but why it is not working on my work laptop is puzzling me !

Would anyone have any idea about identifying what's wrong and how to solve it ?

Comment: Honestly, I think you'd be better off just switching to a package that doesn't have the external dependency issues (perl). *openxlsx* and *writexl* are both probably more stable and likely to work on all platforms.

Comment: I agree, though this is (I think) the only (or one of few) packages that writes to the legacy `.xls` (proprietary) format. If you don't need the older file format, I suggest the package @joran suggested.

Comment: Having said that, creating a file within `C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\R-4.2.2\bin\` seems nonstandard and (to me) suspect. If that really is your current working directory, then try saving to another directory; if that is your current dir and you don't intend that, perhaps something has changed with your RStudio setup; if you are not in that directory, though, that seems like a bug.

Comment: Just to precise things. I do like WriteXLS for some of the options in the xlsx output not present in the other packages. Apart from the 2 versions I use with Rstudio and to rule out any conflicting packages, I did install R4.0.2 and R4.2.2 elsewhere in my Documents folder, and started directly the Rgui of each, hence the strange working directory. But that is not an issue as in R4.0.2 it is working fine to write in the bin folder. It was just for the test. And it is not linked to Rstudio setup has I have the problem anyway outside of it.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with WriteXLS, but I'd be very surprised if it does something (other than maybe creating a really old Excel format) that openxlsx can't. You can control quite a lot of formatting in the Excel document in openxlsx.